# C#, Why does XmlSerializer serialize the base object instead of the Interface?

Tags: c#, interface, xmlserializer

Why does `XmlSerializer` serialize ALL of `Car` when serializing `ICar`? ..instead of just serializing `A` from `ICar`?

I find this odd because when I watch this in the debugger, `icars` only contains `A`, but `test.xml` has `A`, `B` and `C`.

Example code:

```
//IMPLEMENTATION
Cars cars = new Cars(); 

ICars icars = cars;

var iXmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cars));
using (TextWriter iTw = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
{
    iXmls.Serialize(iTw, icar);
}

//CLASS  
[XmlRootAttribute("Cars")]
public class Cars : ICar
{
    private string _A = "Car A"; 
    private string _B = "Car B"; 
    private string _C = "Car C"; 

    public string A { /* get.. set.. */}
    public string B { /* get.. set.. */}
    public string C { /* get.. set.. */}
} 

//INTERFACE
public interface ICars
{
    string A; 
}
```

XML Results:

```
<Cars>
    <A>Car A</A>
    <B>Car B</B>
    <C>Car C</C>
<Cars>
```

Was expecting to get this (but didn't):

```
<Cars>
    <A>Car A</A>
<Cars>
```

Comment: Serialization works only for concrete types whereas interfaces define only the behavior (not State)... You might want to use abstract class instead to achieve what you are looking for..

Comment: @sajoshi Since you can't have an instance of an abstract class, you can't serialize to/from it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you created `XmlSerializer` passing `typeof(Cars)` to it's constructor. XmlSerializer will not work on interface types.

If you want to ignore some Fields, you can use [`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) in your class. See [this post](http://pauliom.wordpress.com/2007/03/19/how-to-ignore-a-fieldproperty-during-serialization/).

Comment: Do you know how I can inherit those values in the same way without creating a new class that initializes those variables manually?

Comment: @PiZzL3 are you talking about deserialization? If so, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he66c7f1.aspx

Comment: I knew about the ingore deal. I was just making a more dynamic way to save things (like if I want to save everything, just several different groupings/combos).

Answer (score 1):

You can't deserialize to `ICar`, so why would you expect to serialize from `ICar`?

Just make a simple type that does what you need.

```
public class PlainOldCar : ICar
{
  public string A {get;set;}
  public PlainOldCar(ICar carSource) //copy constructor
  {
    this.A = carSource.A;
  }
}
```

Comment: I honestly didn't know I couldn't deserialize to ICar. Interfaces are very new to me. That's unfortunately the method I was trying to avoid.